# No sound/volume in Iphone Simulator 4.3 . But plays ok in Iphone simulator 5.1

Tags: xcode4.3, ios4

I am developing a IPhone app to play sound files. My deployment target is 4.0. While trying to play in IPhone Simulator 4.3 it plays with no sound/volume. But it playing ok in Simulator 5.1.

My code:

```
NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"book%i_chapter_%i",book_number,chapter_number];

NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp3" inDirectory:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audio Player: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
else
{
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    //audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    [audioPlayer setVolume:20.0];
    [audioSlider setValue:0.0];
    [audioSlider setMaximumValue:[audioPlayer duration]];

    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Please help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: your code looks alright to me except volume of audio player should be between 0.0 and 1.0, which I don't think it matters for the issue. maybe is there any other part of code with the slider thing that does something wrong?

Comment: Hi , thanks for the comment.

No luck. I can able to hear the sound in Iphone simulator 5.1 and not in 4.3.

Comment: I checked with following condition,

if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
NSLog(@"Playing");

The audio player is still playing, but with no sound.

Comment: hmm I have a sample code that is almost the same as yours and it plays with sound ok in 4.3 simulator. no clue sorry..

Comment: Hi, Could you please post your codes of header and implementation file here. Thanks